# JavaScript cannot access elements in array of div elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I loop through individual elements during their creation I am able to use them and add them to the HTML page, but when I add them to an array it doesn't function well anymore, in fact I am unable to fetch any of the elements I've added to the array at all.

```
const questions = fetchQuestions();

function fetchQuestions() {
    const url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=multiple';

    let questions = []; // HTML array

    fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (json) {
        let results = json.results;
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            // container part
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = 'question-' + i;
            let fieldset = document.createElement('fieldset');
            div.appendChild(fieldset);

            // set question number
            let legend = document.createElement('legend');
            legend.innerHTML = 'Question ' + i;
            fieldset.appendChild(legend);

            // set question text
            let question = document.createElement('p');
            question.innerHTML = results[i].question;
            fieldset.appendChild(question);

            // set question options
            let answerContainer = document.createElement('p');
            let answers = [];
            answers.push(createRadioButton('answer-' + i, results[i].correct_answer, 'answer-' + i + '-correct'));
            answers.push(createRadioButton('answer-' + i, results[i].incorrect_answers[0]));
            answers.push(createRadioButton('answer-' + i, results[i].incorrect_answers[1]));
            answers.push(createRadioButton('answer-' + i, results[i].incorrect_answers[2]));

            shuffle(answers);
            answers.forEach(element => {
                answerContainer.appendChild(element);
            });
            fieldset.appendChild(answerContainer);

            questions.push(div);
        }
    });


    console.log(questions);
    console.log(questions[0]);
    console.log(questions.length);
    return questions;
}

function createRadioButton(name, text, id = false) {
    let label = document.createElement('label');
    let radio = document.createElement('input');
    radio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    radio.setAttribute('name', name);
    if (id) radio.setAttribute('id', id);

    label.append(radio, text);

    return label;
}

function shuffle(array) {
    array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}
```

I first tried using promises and then I was getting a [Object promise] and could access elements, but could not use `appendChild(array[0])` it would throw an error stating that what I'm trying to add isn't an array. How can I overcome this issue and access the elements so that I may be able to add them into my HTML?

Comment: Put everything inside the `.then`

Comment: thanks that did the trick! But what if I want to use the questions array later somewhere I tried writing `console.log(questions[0])` it printed `undefined` in the console.

Comment: You need to make sure that "later" occurs after the `.then` too

Comment: and how can I do that?

Comment: Put it in a function, and call the function inside the `.then`

Comment: that is where the problem lies, that other function should execute every time a user clicks a button it should switch the question that is being previewed, by setting the form elements innerHTML to `question[i]`.

Comment: Either disable the button before the `.then` finishes, or put button clicks in a queue that gets run when the `.then` finishes